# How to use comparison operators to validate the value of number in devexpress

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress

How to use comparison operators such as (<,>,<=,>=,etc.)to validate the value of number?

for example :

```
<dx:ASPxListBox ID="LB_1" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="LB_1" AutoPostBack="false" Caption="AB">
    <Items>
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="A" Value="A" />
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="B" Value="B" />
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="C" Value="C" />
    </Items>
    <ClientSideEvents Validation="function(s,e){
        if(LB_1.GetSelectedIndex()<3){
            alert(LB_1.GetSelectedIndex());
        }        
    }" />
</dx:ASPxListBox>
```

In this case, the Operator can't be read as an operator. 
What is the solution for this case?
Thank you.

Comment: it looks OK. What error do you get? Make sure the Validation handler is called: add console.log('Validation: ' + s.GetSelectedIndex()) before your `if` block and check for this message in Browser's console by hitting F12.

Answer (score 0):

With your current markup unless you manually call the `LB_1.Validate()` from Javascript the `Validation` handler you've specified will not be called. Because you need to add the `<ValidationSettings>` element to your `ASPxListBox` like this:

```
<dx:ASPxListBox ID="LB_1" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="LB_1" AutoPostBack="false" 
                                         Caption="AB">
    <Items>
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="A" Value="A" />
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="B" Value="B" />
        <dx:ListEditItem Text="C" Value="C" />
    </Items>
    <ClientSideEvents Validation="function(s,e){
        if(s.GetSelectedIndex()<3){
            alert(s.GetSelectedIndex() + ', selected value: ' + e.value);
            e.isValid = true;
        }        
    }" />
   <ValidationSettings EnableCustomValidation="True" ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip"
        ErrorText="Select the correct value starting from A to B" SetFocusOnError="True">
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxListBox>
```

So, again, I don't think there is a problem with `<` operator. You just need to setup Validation properly.

More info on the client validation event: [ASPxClientEdit.Validation Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientEdit_Validationtopic)

HTH